# Selecting first line of each 3 line group

Tags: text, notepad++

I have a text document composed of groups of 3 lines. I want to put each of those 3 lines on a single line. So the input is

```
A1 \n
B1 \n
C1 \n
A2 \n
B2 \n
C2 \n
```

(one letter-number on each line)

Should be

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
```

The choice of text editor is not important. I tried to use notepad++.

Comment: Is there really a space before the linebreak?

Comment: Okay sorry actually at each line the is a phrase with spaces and punctuations, slashes etc..

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56456121/372239) to show exactly what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode, in Notepad++:

```
Find:    ([A-Z][0-9])\s*\R([A-Z][0-9])\s*\R([A-Z][0-9])\s*\R
Replace: $1 $2 $3\n
```

### Demo

The pattern target three lines at a time, capturing the letter-number terms in the process.  Then, it replaces with those three capture groups, separated by spaces.

Note that there is a possible edge case which my answer would fail to handle.  If the number of lines in your file is *not* an exact multiple of three, then you might have one or two unprocessed lines at the end of the file.  The only problem would be two lines, actually, since a single unprocessed line would already be in the right format.

Comment: thank you this works with the simple A1 B1 C1 situation but in my case, each line is a phrase..

Comment: Great, and that would be a good topic for another question, but it is not what you asked here.

Comment: If you want to do this with entire lines, then find on the pattern `(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n` and do the same replacement `$1 $2 $3\n`.  [Check the updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7BqJg/2).

Comment: It works with the demo, but when I paste it to search/replace (and with reg exp selected) it doesn't find anything. You have an idea why?

Comment: Try using `\R` instead of `\n` for the line endings.  Maybe you are on Windows, or the file is using CRLF for some reason.